# Google Spreadsheet Formula with imported datas

Tags: function, google-sheets, import

i have imported data from another spreadsheet with importrage, and all is fine!

is it possible to add in a column formulas ?

i am tryng to use a function =IF(H:H=0,"",LEFT(H:H,FIND(",",H:H)-1)) but with imported data don't work

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve this is to import the data wanted and then reference it from the same spreadsheet.

So in your example, you can place the `IMPORTRANGE` formula in the `H` column and then later use the data from it in the formula you have.

Another way to actually be able to access the columns wanted from the imported range is to make use of the `QUERY` function.

For example the formula below will return the values from the first column of the imported range which are different from `0`.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("SPREADSHEET_URL", "RANGE"), "SELECT Col1 WHERE Col1 <> '0'")
```

#### Note

For the `QUERY` formula, the cells from the imported range were formatted to *Plain text* in order to facilitate data manipulation since `QUERY` automatically assigns a data type for the column.

Also in order to format data in the way you want, you can make use of the `CONTAINS` and `FORMAT` clauses from the *Google Query Language*.

#### Reference

- [Google Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage);
- [QUERY function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)